# SiteCore: Web Form not rendering on page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I added a form to a page, but when I preview the page the form doesn't get rendered. There is nothing on the source view. I only need the placeholder on the layout, right? I choose what gets rendered via the layout details for the page item, correct?

- SiteCore 6.5
- Web Forms for Marketers 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you publish? You'll have to publish to get the form to show up.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question with a question? :)